# Multiple Await Async in .Net WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

We have a number of async controllers and services that make use of the `await`/`async` keywords.

A number of the actions look a little like:

```
public async Task<SomeViewModel> Get(int id)
{
    var someData = await _service.GetData(id);
    var someOtherData = await _service.GetMoreData(id);
    return new SomeViewModel
    {
        Data = someData,
        OtherData = someOtherData,
    }
}
```

It might be that the service calls themselves also have multuple `await`s. The `await` will typically be against an `async` call to entity framework, a service bus or a 3rd party web endpoint.

One of my colleagues came to be today suggesting that this kind of code was pointless, that it would simply generate extra work for thread management and the under load we would be actually generate more work for the for the runtime and slow the app down as a result.

Are they right and if so what is considered best practise for `async` / `await` when you have multiple IO bound calls in a Web API request?

Comment: There are good answers to the question already but I wonder what your coworkers think of the team that develops Web API. Do they think that the team is so incompetent that they would work on a feature and add additional complexity for the user to make things slower?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> One of my colleagues came to be today suggesting that this kind of code was pointless, that it would simply generate extra work for thread management and the under load we would be actually generate more work for the for the runtime and slow the app down as a result.

That's amusing, since the opposite is actually true. As other answerers have pointed out, if you're using true asynchronous operations (i.e., not `Task.Run` or anything like that), then there are *fewer* threads used and the application responds *better* under load.

Some folks (not me) have done studies on "average" ASP.NET applications transitioning to `async`, and they have found a 10x to 100x scalability increase when moving to `async` as opposed to blocking calls. You can expect better scalability if your application has more asynchronous work to do.

If you look at a *single* request, and if each operation is done one at a time, then the asynchronous version is *slightly* slower. But if you consider the system as a whole - *especially* under load - the asynchronous version scales better. Another aspect of asynchronous handlers that is often overlooked is that the asynchronous version responds faster to sudden loads than the thread pool can by itself.

Also, asynchronous code makes it easy to execute concurrent requests, which can make the individual requests faster as well:

```
public async Task<SomeViewModel> Get(int id)
{
  var someDataTask = _service.GetData(id);
  var someOtherDataTask = _service.GetMoreData(id);
  await Task.WhenAll(someDataTask, someOtherDataTask);
  return new SomeViewModel
  {
    Data = await someDataTask,
    OtherData = await someOtherDataTask,
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how the code could be rewritten to perform the operations concurrently (was just worrying that all my async calls were sequential). For people using EF to retrieve multiple data sets it's worth noting that a single context doesn't allow this so the sequential await,await bit is probably the best you can do unless you want to spawn multiple contexts (prolly shouldn't).

Answer (score 2):

If you are serving only a single request at a time in your app pool, a blocking solution will be more efficient.

If you have just about any parallelism at all, async/await will probably be more efficient because it results in less threads, and less context switching. Because of this, I/O-bound workloads (where context switching is highly likely if you block) are actually one of the places where async/await shines the best.

As answered by boklucius, async I/O in .NET targets I/O Completion Ports under the covers, which uses a thread pool not to block on I/O but to process I/O *completions*. Using async will definitely not bloat your thread count.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [*Async Performance: Understanding the Costs of Async and Await* by Stephen Toub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx).

I/O is done with completion ports and not with multiple threads, the switching impact should be negligible. As always, it depends on the context, if in doubt measure.

My own experience has shown that the overhead is not that big and the code simplicity is worth it (our use case, a tcp server for a custom obscure protocol with multiple simultaneous slow clients). It was a rewrite of a C++/threads/COM/win32 app, the .net version using heavily await/async has 3x the throughput in 1/5 lines of code, but as I said it depends.